# select from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**hi ,
 i have 3 table :

```
users    
certification    
project
```

i need to select for ech user the list of certification and the list of project like :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
userid | fullname |  list of certification | list of project
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | xX       | ITIL ,Cisco,..         | PROj 1 ,Proj 2 ...
```

i try this**

```
select users.fullname,users.team,users.jobtitle,certif= STUFF(
       (SELECT ','+ certifiacte
        FROM dbo.certification a
        INNER JOIN dbo.Users ar ON ar.UserId = a.UserId

        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),porj= STUFF(
       (SELECT ','+ project
        FROM dbo.project a
        INNER JOIN dbo.Users ar ON ar.UserId = a.UserId

        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
 from Users
```

but the problem  is  i get the list of all certification and project saved in database in all row. but i need for each users list of project and certification related to him only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time this happens, it means that you are not correlating.   Your subselects are not related to your outer query.

You need to do this instead:

```
select ar.fullname,ar.team,ar.jobtitle,certif= STUFF(
       (SELECT ','+ certifiacte
        FROM dbo.certification a
        WHERE ar.UserId = a.UserId    
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),porj= STUFF(
       (SELECT ','+ project
        FROM dbo.project a
        WHERE ar.UserId = a.UserId
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
from Users ar
```